# Reliability of R Package on Covariance Matrix Shrinkage

Tags: programming, covariance-matrix, covariance-estimation

I recently used a R package CovTools in R with the command CovEst.2003LW(X), where X is your sample covariance matrix as an input, to compute the shrunk covariance matrix (an estimate that is closest to the true covariance matrix). For reference, the package resides here:

https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/CovTools/html/CovEst.2003LW.html

Can any portfolio optimization or R experts provide their insights into whether this package is trustable? The package is based on the famous paper "Honey, I Shrunk the Sample Covariance Matrix" by Ledoit and Wolf (2003).

Comment: If you do not get an answer here, but might want to ask at R-SIG-Finance (https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-finance). Several packages on CRAN implement Ledoit--Wolf (e.g. `RiskPortfolios::covEstimation` or `BurStFin::var.shrink.eqcor`), so you also compare results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code provided from the authors directly. Michael Wolf has a whole library of examples [here](https://www.econ.uzh.ch/en/people/faculty/wolf/publications.html#Programming_Code) in different programming languages. For the "Honey, I Shrunk the Covariance Matrix" paper you can check out this [Github repo](https://github.com/MikeWolf007/covShrinkage).